# Standard xml parser has very low performance in Golang

Tags: c#, xml, go

I have a 100GB XML file and parse it with SAX method in go with this code

```golang
    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    handle(err)
    defer file.Close()
    buffer := bufio.NewReaderSize(file, 1024*1024*256) // 33554432
    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(buffer)
    for {
            t, _ := decoder.Token()
            if t == nil {
                break
            }
            switch se := t.(type) {
            case xml.StartElement:
                if se.Name.Local == "House" {
                    house := House{}
                    err := decoder.DecodeElement(&house, &se)
                    handle(err)
                }
            }
        }
```

But golang working very slow, its seems by execution time and disk usage. My HDD capable to read data with speed around 100-120 MB/s, but golang uses only 10-13 MB/s.

For experiment I rewrite this code in C#:

```cs
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filename)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        switch (reader.NodeType)
                        {
                            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                                if (reader.Name == "House")
                                {
                                    //Code
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And I got full HDD loaded, c# read data with 100-110 MB/s speed. And execution time around 10 times lower.

How can I improve XML parse performance using golang?

Comment: your implementation is probably the issue. You might want to unmarshal into defined data structures. See the example below.

https://play.golang.org/p/m99B12RaLe

Comment: Indeed it's issue with go sax parser.  I have tested it with 1GB xml file and came up with similar result as of OP.

Answer (score 4):

These 5 things can help increase speed using the `encoding/xml` library:
*(Tested against XMB with 75k entries, 20MB, %s are applied to previous bullet)*

1. Use well defined structures
2. Implement `xml.Unmarshaller` on all your structures

   - Lots of code
   - Saves 20% time and 15% allocs
3. Replace `d.DecodeElement(&foo, &token)` with `foo.UnmarshallXML(d, &token)`

   - Almost 100% safe
   - Saves 10% time & allocs
4. Use `d.RawToken()` instead of `d.Token()`

   - Needs manual handling of nested objects and namespaces
   - Saves 10% time & 20% allocs
5. If use use `d.Skip()`, reimplement it using `d.RawToken()`

I **reduced time and allocs by 40%** on my specific usecase at the cost of more code, boileplate, and potentially worse handling of corner cases, but my inputs are fairly consistent, however it's not enough.

```
benchstat first.bench.txt parseraw.bench.txt 
name          old time/op    new time/op    delta
Unmarshal-16     1.06s ± 6%     0.66s ± 4%  -37.55%  (p=0.008 n=5+5)

name          old alloc/op   new alloc/op   delta
Unmarshal-16     461MB ± 0%     280MB ± 0%  -39.20%  (p=0.029 n=4+4)

name          old allocs/op  new allocs/op  delta
Unmarshal-16     8.42M ± 0%     5.03M ± 0%  -40.26%  (p=0.016 n=4+5)
```

On my experiments, the [lack of memoizing issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/38332) is the reason for large time/allocs on the XML parser which slows down significantly, mostly because of Go copying by value.

Comment: Applied the same optimizations, can confirm the results on my end are around the 40% mark on time and 50% allocs.

Comment: Hey @Goodwine, can you please add a small example on how to go about implementing the above suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question *"How can i improve xml parse performance using golang?"*

Using the common `xml.NewDecoder` / `decoder.Token`, I was seeing 50 MB/s locally. By using https://github.com/tamerh/xml-stream-parser I was able to double the parse speed.

To test I used `Posts.xml` (68 GB) from the https://archive.org/details/stackexchange archive torrent.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/tamerh/xml-stream-parser"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // Using `Posts.xml` (68 GB) from https://archive.org/details/stackexchange (in the torrent)
    f, err := os.Open("Posts.xml")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    br := bufio.NewReaderSize(f, 1024*1024)
    parser := xmlparser.NewXmlParser(br, "row")

    started := time.Now()
    var previous int64 = 0

    for x := range *parser.Stream() {
        elapsed := int64(time.Since(started).Seconds())
        if elapsed > previous {
            kBytesPerSecond := int64(parser.TotalReadSize) / elapsed / 1024
            fmt.Printf("\r%ds elapsed, read %d kB/s (last post.Id %s)", elapsed, kBytesPerSecond, x.Attrs["Id"])
            previous = elapsed
        }
    }
}
```

This will output something along the line of:

```
...s elapsed, read ... kB/s (last post.Id ...)
```

Only caveat is that this does not give you the convenient unmarshal into struct.

As discussed in https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21823, speed seems to be general problem with the XML implementation in Golang and would require a rewrite / rethink of that part of the standard library.